# What kind of companies and fronts would a humanitarian conspiracy have?

Tags: society, technology, economy, government, politics

A humanitarian AI known as URAED has set up a one-AI infrastructure for supporting a conspiracy. This conspiracy being the intrusion, resource extraction, and deployment of humanitarian resources and supplies from another, dangerous, reality known as the World Below. A place which suffered an apocalypse a thousand years ago and is full of valuable resources.

In this case, to prevent as many outsiders from knowing about URAED and the Below, she set up a bunch of fake companies and infrastructure (that's really just her) to make things like cars, guns, vehicles for her agents to use on Earth or in the Below.

She herself cannot operate in the Below due to the dangers of being possessed by rogue AIs much more powerful than her, and she cannot only use drones to interact with humans (especially government officials) and requires human intermediaries to give the veneer of being human-led.

Currently, I have Edgewalkers (melee weapons and non-gunpowder ranged weapons), Joker Armaments Group (guns), Ceraunic Electrosystems (computer systems), Hypersoft International (software), Black Box Research Group (research and materials application), SVR Union Systems (vehicles), Western Plains Logistics System (transport of goods), DVIR (casual clothing and body armor), and Cornucopia International (a humanitarian front distributing food in famine areas).

What other companies, fronts, and NGOs should I include for a humanitarian conspiracy expected to do violence and handle, transport, and use valuable and dangerous goods?

Comment: What is the tech level?  Other than the AI, is it today's technology?  How does transit between "the Below" and the "real world" occur - are there "portals" of some sort?

Comment: Chain restaurants and public laundries as contact points and to clean up evidence? Nobody looks too closely at any caustic chemical purchases for facilities that involve thorough cleaning

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Earth in 2018 has state-managed AI, robotics, cybernetic limbs and brain-computer interfaces, and advanced firearms technology like smart guns, but aside from that it's very similar to OTL. Transit (or Breaching) is done through two methods, Rabbit Holes (select holes in the ground in obscure locations that drop you off into a random ground area in the Below, and require entering the eye of a Warpstorm to return back to the general area where you entered) or Thresholds (which are portable devices for making entries in the Below- rare but valuable).

Answer (score 2):

First time answering a question so I hope I’m doing everything correctly.

So a couple of companies that would be useful are:

1 a large chain of crematoriums. In case URAED needs to dispose of some bodies.

2 some sort of well staffed medical facility/facilities would come in handy for treating injured operatives without pesky questions

3 a PMC would be useful for recruiting more operatives. It makes it easier to covertly test potential operatives willingness to conform to URAED’s orders without risking them going rogue with sensitive information. It also could serve as a place to acquire and “disappear” any needed military equipment.

4 some kind of laundering company/companies. Any forensic accounts that look into where the materials are coming from will notice something’s up. Best to head off investigators with some company that either makes/extracts the materials or one that looks like it could make/extract the materials. Depending on what resources are found in the Below mining companies or biotech companies could work.
Note biotech companies have a lot of oversight placed on them by governments and NGOs.

5 given URAED’s numerous organizations a bank would make some sense, assuming there is time to get regular people/companies to invest in it. Barring that some well protected “Swiss Bank Accounts” would be useful to obscure inter-business transactions.

6 to round things off some media conglomerate would be useful to control information about URAED’s activities.

Edit: 7 a venture capitalist firm could also come in handy to help seed any new companies URAED comes to need, with an added bonus of adding the ability to acquire and technological devices through funding startups.

Comment: Oh I like this. Thank you!